# User with bank account info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following doubt, I hope you can help me. I have a project in Rails which allows any user to register on the website, this user has the option to enter information from his bank account for the site to make the deposit for his services, then I have a user model that Is related to account_bank model:
How can I make the url appear like this www.sitio.com/usuario/pepe/cuenta_banco?

If I do it in the traditional way, I get it www.sitio.com/usuario/pepe/cuenta_banco/123

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic [because it is not in english](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts). Either ask in english or go to http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That's to do with [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) where you can set up the route any way you want. Why do you need the `?` version?

Comment: Hi!, i have rails v4.2.5 (c9.io) and in my route file i put this code "resources :user do resources bank_account end"